# Windows XP/7 Disabling Users Accounts via. CMD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, administrator

How can I disable a user account from the command line?

In Windows XP or 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
net user [username] /ACTIVE:NO [/DOMAIN]
```

Hint: only add the /DOMAIN flag if you're not dealing with local users.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if the answer is accurate :)

Comment: I don't have the reputation yet :S