# How do I disable a user's account on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

As an administrator, how can I disable (not delete) a user's account on Windows 7?

I couldn't find anything in the "Manage Accounts" section of Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Run `lusrmgr`. Select Users, double click on user name, check "Account is disabled."

Or to do it from the command line: [Windows XP/7 Disabling Users Accounts via. CMD](https://superuser.com/questions/164525/windows-xp-7-disabling-users-accounts-via-cmd)

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. `lusrmgr.msc` is the primary way that I manage local accounts on my PCs. You can certainly disable a user from that menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use powershell:

```
$User = Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_UserAccount' -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='User name here'"
$User.Disabled = $true
$User.Put()
```